# Is there a way to lock-on to larger monsters?

Tags: god-eater-2

I've been playing God Eater 2: Rage Burst lately and I recognize a lot of similarities between it and Monster Hunter and Freedom Wars. In both of those games, however, you were able to fix the camera on the large monsters so that they never got out of your sight.

In God Eater 2, however, I have been unable to figure out how to lock-on to these larger targets in the 20-ish hours I've been playing. It was fine for a while, but I just got to Difficulty 4 missions and it's getting a bit difficult to stay alive during these tougher fights since I can't always see my opponent. Is there a way to lock-on to large monsters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. When using a melee weapon, press and hold L1 to lock-on to a target. In gun form, pressing and holding L1 will cause you to zoom in. I'd been using the zoom function but I never tried it for the melee weapons.